# Update existing 'paragraph' entity while changing the ID is not supported

Tags: entities

I'm trying to update a paragraph with this code:

```
$entityManager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
      $paragraph = $entityManager->getStorage('paragraph')->load('1');
      $paragraph->set('field_test','testValue');
      $paragraph->save();
```

But I received this error:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Update existing 'paragraph' entity while changing the ID is not supported. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 846 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
```

Do you know why?

P.s. If I try to update with the last ID it works. It doesn't work only for old Paragraphs.

Comment: Maybe you have a hook that changes the ID to latest, thus; would explain why no error on last and error on the rest.

Comment: Paragraphs are not stand-alone entities. The error could be caused by an older paragraph now orphaned or you load an outdated revision. I'm not sure if it makes sense to load and save a paragraph out of context. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It might also be related to revisions and possibly a failed update process.  There are a lot of issues around updating to 8.7? and not having a default revision field properly set by the update process.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the paragraphs through their parent entity to get the active revisions:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  // load only nodes where this paragraph reference field exists and has content
  ->exists('field_paragraph')
  ->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $paragraphs = $node->field_paragraph->referencedEntities();
  foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    if ($paragraph->hasField('field_foo')) {
      $paragraph->field_foo->value = 'bar';
      $paragraph->save();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: got the same error